# Can we solve for (or approximate) $m$ from $ \frac{(2n-m)!}{(n-m)!} = c$?

Tags: combinatorics, factorial, analytic-combinatorics

I need to solve the following equation for $m$:

$$
\frac{(2n-m)!}{(n-m)!} = c
$$

where $m$ and $n$ are natural numbers in the order of 10 with $n \ge m$ and $c$ is a real-valued constant (edit: it's a natural number actually, HT @Kaind). Any chance this can be solved/approximated analytically?

Comment: In the real domain, we could have *approximations*. Would that be OK ?

Comment: Do you have specific values of c and n? or just a general equation. The former might be much easier.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: haha, I added 'approximated' the second you wrote this comment. So yes, I anticipate this is the only way, so approximation would be okay.

Comment: @Kaind: I need the 'general' solution

Comment: Thanks so much!

Comment: @monade 1 easy observation is that $c$ will be a natural number as $2n - m > n - m$. You could view the LHS as $^{n +t}P_{t}$ where $0 \le t,n $

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind is Stirling's approximation.

Comment: @Kaind: yes, good observation - c is a natural number. What does $^{n+1}P_t$ refer to? I'm not familiar with this notation / what $P$ represents.

Comment: permutations of $t$ objects from $n+t$ objects.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The goal being to get an *approximation* of $m$ from the equation
$$\frac{(2n-m)!}{(n-m)!} = c$$ in the real domain, I shall convert the problem to the gamma function  and logarithms (just as @NN2 did); remember that the *log gamma* function is available is most environments. So , the problem is to solve for $m$ the equation
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 n+1-m)}{\Gamma (n+1-m)}\right)=k \qquad \text{with} \qquad k=\log(c)\tag 1$$ The fact that $0 \leq m \leq n$ implies that the solution exists only if
$$\log(n!) \leq k \leq \log \left(\frac{(2 n)!}{n!}\right)$$

To stay as simple as possible, in a first step, we shall assume that the lhs of $(1)$ can write as
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 n+1-m)}{\Gamma (n+1-m)}\right)\sim\frac {\alpha+\beta \,m}{1+\gamma\,m}$$ and the parameters will be defined using three specific points, namely $m=0$, $m=\frac n 2$ and $m=n$.

This gives
$$\alpha =\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 n+1)}{\Gamma (n+1)}\right)$$
$$\gamma=-\frac{\color{red}{\alpha} +\log (\Gamma (n+1))-2 \log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3
   n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\right)}{n \left(\log (\Gamma
   (n+1))-\log \left(\frac{\Gamma \left(\frac{3 n}{2}+1\right)}{\Gamma
   \left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}\right)\right)}$$
$$\beta=\frac{(\color{red}{\gamma}  n+1) \log (\Gamma (n+1))-\color{red}{\alpha} }{n}$$ The *approximation* is then
$$m_0=\frac{\alpha -k}{\gamma  k-\beta }$$
Now, we can polish the root making for example one single iteration of Newton method giving
$$m_1=m_0- \frac{\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (2 n+1-m_0)}{\Gamma (n+1-m_0)}\right)-k} {\psi (n+1-m_0)-\psi (2 n+1-m_0) }$$

For a test, I shall use $n=20$ and $45 \leq k \leq 67$. The results are given below.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
k & m_0 & m_1 & \text{exact} \\
 45 & 18.9257 & 19.1467 &  19.1414 \\
 46 & 18.4909 & 18.7665 &  18.7595 \\
 47 & 18.0369 & 18.3531 &  18.3451 \\
 48 & 17.5625 & 17.9063 &  17.8979 \\
 49 & 17.0665 & 17.4253 &  17.4171 \\
 50 & 16.5471 & 16.9097 &  16.9020 \\
 51 & 16.0027 & 16.3583 &  16.3516 \\
 52 & 15.4315 & 15.7703 &  15.7647 \\
 53 & 14.8315 & 15.1445 &  15.1401 \\
 54 & 14.2004 & 14.4796 &  14.4763 \\
 55 & 13.5357 & 13.7740 &  13.7718 \\
 56 & 12.8347 & 13.0263 &  13.0249 \\
 57 & 12.0942 & 12.2346 &  12.2339 \\
 58 & 11.3110 & 11.3971 &  11.3968 \\
 59 & 10.4812 & 10.5117 &  10.5117 \\
 60 & 9.60044 & 9.57631 &  9.57630 \\
 61 & 8.66393 & 8.58850 &  8.58835 \\
 62 & 7.66621 & 7.54579 &  7.54542 \\
 63 & 6.60106 & 6.44550 &  6.44493 \\
 64 & 5.46142 & 5.28484 &  5.28414 \\
 65 & 4.23917 & 4.06086 &  4.06018 \\
 66 & 2.92502 & 2.77048 &  2.77001 \\
 67 & 1.50818 & 1.41059 &  1.41041
\end{array}
\right)$$ This looks to be more than decent inspite of the extreme simplicity of the model used for the generation of $m_0$.

**Edit**  *(too long for the comment section)*

Concerning your code, I should not use *log(gamma(x))* but *loggamma(x)* (available in Python and much more efficient since you work with huge numbers); you sill need to use $\log \left(\frac{x}{y}\right)=\log(x)-\log(y)$ for each ratio of gamma functions.

I don't see any mistake in your code. However, I found one in my answer (a minus sign was missing in front of the expression of $\gamma$. **Sorry for that**).

To check the results of your test case, you should  have
$$\alpha=67.985023254003910399$$
$$\beta=-2.3627320266334409125$$
$$\gamma=-0.025516616439785586046$$
$$m_0=11.87544422099728158 \quad \text{instead of} \qquad 12$$
$$m_1=12.00052654314102290$$

I still work this interesting problem. If anything interesting, I shall post here.

**Update**

Trying the above for $n=123\sqrt \pi$ and $c=e^{1234}$ gives $m_0=35.5230$ and $m_1=33.3622$ while the solution is $m=33.3534$

Comment: This looks great and the precision is impressive. Thanks so much already! I just tried to reproduce $m_0$, but did not quite succeed. Here's my code (Python - but should be generic): https://gist.github.com/m-guggenmos/b1e2d0d4d72e7b07976f2c90c692cc4f

The values for $m_0$ are off quite a bit and different from yours. Most likely there's err on my side, since I'm not familiar with the underlying mathematics. Do you have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @monade. Have a look at my edit. The mistake was mine (just add a minus sign in front of *gam*). If you consider that this is a valuable answer, may be you could accept it. Cheers.

Comment: I changed the formula for $m_1$. The *polygamma* function is available in Python. Could you modify your code and compute $m_0$ and $m_1$ and send it ?

Comment: @robjohn. Any idea ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @monade : Glad to see that the question has been reopened.

Comment: Awesome :-). I was able to reproduce $m_0$ and $m_1$. Code is here: https://gist.github.com/m-guggenmos/07fccbe79f0a97a8c45ac55b42923d5e

What I had not mentioned is that the constant $c$ has some noise to it, i.e. it is not necessarily a natural number (and the resulting non-naturalness of $m$ carries meaning in this case). The great thing is that this is not a problem using your method. Initial tests show that $m_1$ truthfully recovers (at least) the first 2-3 decimal points of the solution, which is all I need. The solution is also sufficiently fast. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is no analytical solution for $(m,n) \in\Bbb N^2$. For numerical solutions, the time complexity of the problem is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ (the problem is a two dimensional problem for $(m,n)$ ).

This method here provides a solution with the time complexity around $\mathcal{O}(n)$.

First, we extend the problem from $(m,n) \in\Bbb N^2$ to $(m,n) \in \Bbb R^2$ and solve the new problem
$$\frac{\Gamma(2n-m+1)}{\Gamma(n-m+1)}=c \tag{1}$$
with the function Gamma defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)  (for $n\in \Bbb N$, we have $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$)

For the sake of simplicity, let's denote $(x,y) = (n,n-m+1)$, then
\begin{align}
(1)&\iff \Gamma(x+y)=c\Gamma(y) \\
&\iff x =\Gamma^{-1}(c\Gamma(y))-y\tag{2}
\end{align}

According to [this result](https://mathoverflow.net/a/28977/62193), the inverse Gamma function $\Gamma^{-1}(z)$ can be approximated by

$$\Gamma^{-1}(z) \approx \frac{\ln \left(\frac{z+d}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{W \left( \frac{\ln \left(\frac{z+d}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{e} \right)}  + \frac{1}{2}$$
with $d = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e} - \Gamma(1.461632) \approx 0.036534 $ and $W(x)$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Hence, from $(2)$, we have

$$x \approx f(y):=\frac{\ln \left(\frac{c\Gamma(y)+d}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{W \left( \frac{\ln \left(\frac{c\Gamma(y)+d}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)}{e} \right)}  + \frac{1}{2} -y \tag{3}$$

*Remark:* You could also use the [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation)  for $(2)$ and find the relationship of $(x,y)$ as follows
$$(x+y)\ln(x+y) -(x+y) -y\ln(y)+y \approx \ln(c) \tag{4}$$
But the formula $(4)$ is not explicit and besides less accurate than $(3)$.
$$$$
Return back to the formula $(3)$ and the initial problem, it suffices to find the natural numbers $(x,y) \in \Bbb N^2$ such that $$1 \le y \le x \le N$$ with $N$ in the order of $10$ (as mentionned in the question). The algorithm can be as follows

> For $y$ from $1$ to $N$
> $\qquad$ Calculate $z = f(y)$ with $(3)$
> $\qquad$ Stop the loop if $z > N$
> $\qquad$ Check if $(x,y)$ satisfies the equation $(2)$ where $x \in \{[z]-K,...,[z]+K\}$
> $\qquad$ If any $(x,y)$ is found then $m=x-y-1$

($[z]$ is the entier part of $z$ and $K$ is delibrately fixed but small to prevent the approximation error of $(3)$ , for instant, you can take $K= 2$)

The advantage of this method is the time complexity is $\mathcal{O}(N)$ instead of  $\mathcal{O}(N^2)$ with a naive numerical method (for example, a nested for-loops over $m$ and $n$).

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to work on my problem! It's a great solution. Let me ask a clarification: with the *naive numerical method* you refer to simply looping across all $m\in{0..N}$ and finding the specific $\hat{m}$ for which the original equation is satisfied?

Comment: I modified my last staments in the answer. In fact, naive numerical methods are just methods using 2 for-loops over $m$ and $n$. My method uses 1 loop over $y=n = 1,...,N$. Furthermore, the algorithms we know (the algorithm I proposed and the one proposed by Claude Leibovici)  have the time complexity of $\mathcal{O}(N) = \mathcal{M} \times N$  with $\mathcal{M}$  is a constant factor depending on the approximating function   $m = f(n)$. Hence, any further improvement lies on the construction of the approximating function $f(n)$.

Comment: Thanks. It seems I might have caused some confusion. While I need the solution to this equation for arbitrary values of $n$ and $c$, in each *specific* instance $n$ and $c$ are known. This means, each specific solution could in principle be computed simply by trying out all possible values of $m$ (i.e. only order of 10). However, for other reasons this is not feasible in my case, hence I was looking for an analytic solution / approximation.

Comment: @monade  I see. In the case where $n$ is given, the $\bar{m} \in \Bbb R$ (the approximation of $m \in \Bbb N$) can be deduced directly from the equation $(3)$, no for-loop is needed. And the $m \in \Bbb N$ can be obtained from trial with $m \in \{\bar{m} \pm K \}$  (as the proposed solutions are based on approximation, this last step is necessary).

Comment: Using Lambert is a good idea but I have a problem : the equation $(2)$ has to be solved for $y$, not for $x$. Am I correct ? Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the equation $(2)$ is used to solve for $x$ **and** $y$ under the assumption that we need to find $m$ **and** $n$ ($m,n$ are unknown, $c$ is known). But if $m$ is unknown, $n,c$ are known, the problem becomes easier and there is not necessary to use for-loop over $y$. For this problem, I need to modify the equation $(2)$ to solve for $y$.